# How to install: caress server node server.js . Error: 'Cannot find module '....buffertools.node'

Tags: node.js, debugging, command-line, npm, server

I am installing the the [library found from MIT students using TUIO](https://github.com/ekryski/caress-server). According to their instructions I was supposed to start the server but I got an error.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\server1.1>node examples/server.js
   info  - socket.io started
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/buffertools.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\server1.1\node_modules\buffertool
s\buffertools.js:26:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following there steps and got my server stared.

I think you are missing `npm i` after cloning repo.

please do `npm i` and try starting server

Comment: `npm WARN package.json caress-server00.2.1 No license field.`

`npm WARN prefer global node-gyp03.3.1 should be installed with -g`

Comment: 'npm ERR! buffertools@2.1.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`'
'npm ERR! Exit status 1'

Comment: can you please add full stack trace. so that i can help

Comment: OK, now what because I don't see what its saying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dependency packages before you can run your project.
`npm install` looks for the packages listed in the `package.json` file and installs them with their dependencies recursively.

If you are getting specific error in installation of particular package, it could be internet issue/os issue and most probably node and npm version issue. Make sure you are using a stable version of node, its version no should be even.